# How to browse an inheritance system?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, components, entity

I'm making an entity/component system and I'm having some problem making a function that can select entity based on their inherited components. Let's take an example:

```
Animal (1)
    Dog (2)
        Doberman (3)
        Rottweiler (3)
    Cat (2)
        Siamese (3)
        Persian (3)
```

If you're unfamiliar with the entity component system, let's say that if I want a Doberman named "Rex", I would do something like:

```
let Rex: Entity = createEntity("Doberman");
```

The Doberman component extends to Dog, and Dog extends to Animal. So Rex receives the properties of all those three components.

Now when I want to select all entities that have the Animal component (ie. "selectEntities(Animal)"), I also want to select Dogs, Cats, Dobermans, etc. In other words: all inherited components. And that's where I'm stuck, because it must be dynamic and take into account any chain of inherited components, no matter how many levels there are in it. In my first versions, components could be inherited by only one other component, which made a simple loop an easy solution to browse all entities.

Now a specific component can still extend to only one other component (Dog to Animal), but it can be extended by an infinite number of components (Dog from Doberman and Rottweiler). And I can't figure out how to get all the components from a parent. Is it doable with just an imbrication/interlocking of loops?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the original problem. The question should have been "How to iterate over a nested object?", and this has a simple solution: recursive call.

So we could do something like that:

```
public getInheritedComponents(component: string) : object {
    let inheritees: object = {};
    let current : Component = this.getComponent(component);
    for (let inheritee in current.inherited) {
        inheritees[inheritee] = current.inherited[inheritee];
        let subinheritees = this.getInheritedComponents(inheritee);
        for (let subinheritee in subinheritees) {
            inheritees[subinheritee] = subinheritees[subinheritee];
        }
    }
    return inheritees;
}
```

And the lesson of the day would be: "Don't fight a logical problem at dusk, let the night pass." :)